# Add GLKVector3 to an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add a GLKVector3 object into an NSMutableArray. I understand that NSMutableArrays will only accept certain objects so what would be the best way for me too add a GLKVector3 to an array.

Here is a sample of code:

```
        for(id basenormal in [jsnmvtx objectForKey:@"baseNormals"]){
            [basenormalsVectorArrays addObject:GLKVector3MakeWithArray(basenormal)];
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `GLKVector3` is a C-style `struct`, not an object. So it doesn't know how to respond to `retain` or `release` and therefore won't work with an `NSArray`.

What you can do is wrap each one into an `NSValue` as that's an object type and it knows how to keep arbitrary C types inside it. It's not especially neat because you're straddling the border between C and Objective-C but e.g.

```
GLKVector3 someVector;

[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&someVector objCType:@encode(GLKVector3)]];

...

GLKVector3 storedVector;

NSValue *value = ... something fetched from array ...;
[value getValue:&storedVector];

// storedVector now has the value of someVector
```

That'll copythe contents of `someVector` into the `NSValue` and then copy them out again into `storedVector`.

You can use `valueWithPointer:` and `pointerValue` if you'd prefer to keep a reference to `someVector` in your array rather than copying contents, though then you'll need to be careful about manual memory management, so a better solution might be to use `NSData` as in:

```
// we'll need the vector to be on the heap, not the stack
GLKVector3 *someVector = (GLKVector3 *)malloc(sizeof(GLKVector3));

[array addObject:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:someVector length:sizeof(GLKVector3) freeWhenDone:YES]];
// now the NSData object is responsible for freeing the vector whenever it ceases
// to exist; you needn't do any further manual management

...

GLKVector3 *storedVector = (GLKVector3 *)[value bytes];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting this error now and not sure how to correct it:

implicit conversion of an objective-c pointer to 'float *' is disallowed with arc

Comment: On what line does that happen?